# Construct a std::map<T,U> from a std::vector<std::pair<T,U> >

Tags: c++, c++98

How can I construct a `std::map<std::string, Foo>` from a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Foo> >`? It seems the std::map can be constructed from a input iterator.

**UPDATE**

Incidentally, I need to convert the strings in the vector to their lower case forms when adding them to the map. This is because I wish to use the map to get a sorted version of whats in the vector.

Comment: Yes, there is a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) that takes a pair of iterators. Have you tried using it?

Comment: [After the update] If you need to modify the keys before you add the items, but can't modify them in the vector, then you need to manually loop over the vector and add the entries one by one.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Unless the vector can first be modified in place (and then use Konrad's solution).

Comment: If you want to sort the map by lower case keys, it might be a cleaner option to give the map a comparator that compares lower case strings.

Comment: If you just want to sort the entries, using sort() with a comparator would be even better.

Answer (score 6):

Every standard library container can be constructed from an iterator range. In your case:

```
std::map<std::string, Foo> mymap(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
```

If you want to add the *lower-case* versions of the strings, you need to pass the values through a transforming iterator. Unfortunately that’s not included in standard C++ but it’s rather straightforward to implement. [Boost also includes a version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html):

```
// Make the pair's key lower-case
std::pair<std::string, Foo> make_lower(std::pair<std::string, Foo> x) {
    std::transform(x.first.begin(), x.first.end(), x.first.begin(), ::tolower);
    return x;
}

std::map<std::string, int> mymap(
    boost::make_transform_iterator(myvector.begin(), make_lower),
    boost::make_transform_iterator(myvector.end(), make_lower));
```

[Here’s a complete, running demonstration](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d415f01771236a34)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::map<std::string, Foo> m;
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Foo> > vec;

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Foo> >::iterator it = vec.begin();

for(;it!=vec.end();++it)
{
  std::string temp = it->first;

  std::for_each(temp.begin(), temp.end(), 
        [](char& c){ tolower((unsigned char)c);}); 

  m[temp] = it->second;

 }
```

Comment: @KerrekSB yeah I realized that :D

Answer (score 0):

As per the map constructor definition,The function template argument **InputIterator** shall be an input iterator type that points to elements of a type from which **value_type** objects can be constructed (in map, **value_type** is an alias of pair< const key_type, mapped_type > )

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Foo> > V;
//Fill the Vector V using make_pair...or other method
//Vector iterator can be used to construct the Map since you get the pair
std::map<std::string, Foo> M(V.begin(),V.end());
```